# How to make page printable on clicking ctrl+P in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf, yii2

I'm working on a demo project and i need to know how to make the page printable on just ctrl+P click. When i'm printing it just giving me a document without css and styles.
Here is the result I'm getting and the pdf which I want to get.[image]
[image]

and I want this-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to write css for print media normal css will not work here. 
so do these steps

1. create new css file named as print.css
2. copy css class from your normal stylesheet but only those class that used in your above layout not all.
3. hide those part that you dont want to show on print.

like

```
.navigation, header, footer{display :none!important;}
```

now include this css file in your view file with extra attribute i. e. `screen="print"`

so full path look like this. 
`<link href="path/to/print.css" screen="print" />`

or you can do this just by putting all css class in your main file under media query. 
like `@media(print){
// all your css classes that involves in your layout and extra css to hide div that you dont want
}`